# How to create/fill a Table with the content extracted from another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to put all results of a query in a output table. I am using Toad - Oracle SQL. 
the query is

```
SELECT P_ID, M_NAME FROM CLTY_TDL_TRAM
```

I need the results of this query to be put in a new table with column names `NAME_SD, HOUSE_NAME` in a new table named `CLTY_TDL_TRAM` 
I am not sure if i should use SQL or PLSQL.

Comment: You've tagged this for SQL Server (a Microsoft product) and Oracle (an Oracle product).  The syntax for creating a table from a query will differ between the two.  Which are you actually using?  Are you really sure that you want to create a new table?  Having the same data in two different tables in the same database is generally a bad idea that, among other things, violates normalization rules.

Comment: i am sorry for the ambiguity in my question. i am using toad -oracle. I need to run queries on the oracle database. then put the output in a flat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table as the results of your query.  Read up on the create table statement.  Basically:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name [ ( column [, ...] ) ] 
AS
SELECT [ ( column [, ...] ) ] FROM existing table_name
```

To go to a flat file as your post title says, read up on the SPOOL command, then run as a script in Toad.

Comment: thank you for your reply. can i directly write the results of the query into a flat file with SPOOL command